# sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Userdb.post

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

```
##CONFIGURE TABLES
class Userdb(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))

    # This will act like a List of BlogPost objects attached to each User.
    # The "author" refers to the author property in the BlogPost class.
    post = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author", lazy='dynamic')

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "blog_posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"),nullable=False)
    # Create reference to the User object, the "posts" refers to the posts protperty in the User class.
    author = relationship("Userdb", back_populates="post", lazy='dynamic')
    # Create Foreign Key, "users.id" the users refers to the tablename of User.

    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.String(10000), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
```

sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Userdb.post - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This code works absolutely fine for me

Comment: Thanks, for checking but I still got the same error in my system but if I run the same code in another system it works, So, what's the problem in my system, is it a version error.